# No matching %macro error in sas

Tags: macros, sas

When I ran the following code, three errors show in the log:
ERROR: No matching %MACRO statement for this %MEND statement.
ERROR: The macro NO is still executing and cannot be redefined.
ERROR: A dummy macro will be compiled.
I was wondering if it is the black hole problem. But I can not find out any syntax error. Can anyone tell me what's the problem? thank you!

```
%Macro table(x);
  data m_&x; set A (where=(seqno=0));
    LENGTH DD_&x 8;
  run;
%mend table;

data _null_;
  Do u=1 to 17;
    call execute ('%nrstr(%table('||u||'))');
  end;
run;


%macro sumup_DD (x, Startdate, Enddate,i);
  data B; set A (where=(seqno=&i));
    DD_&x=sum(of &Startdate-&Enddate);
  run;
  proc append base=m_&x data=B;
  run;
%mend sumup_DD;

%macro no;
  %do n=1 %to 17;
    data _null_; set A;
      call execute('%nrstr(%sumup_DD ('||&n||','||rr&n||','||rr%eval(&n+1)||','||seqno||'))');
    run;
  %end;
%mend no; 
%no;
```

Comment: It rather sounds like you did something wrong in an earlier execution and that it influences your consecutive runs of the code. Can you confirm that those are indeed the errors you get on a first run in a fresh SAS session?

Comment: Typo -- line 5 in your code should be `%mend tables;` not `%mend table;`.

Comment: @Shorack In a fresh SAS session on a first run," %no" can not be executed.It is recognized as part of the Macro command.

Comment: @DomPazz Thank you! I have corrected it. But I don't this is the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the bug. It is indeed the black hole problem, which is caused by a single quotation mark in one of my comments! This single quotation made the '%mend' be recognized as a literal token. Thus all the following codes I ran was recognized as part of the macro.

Answer (score 0):

*I found this a bug in my script, where I was using the condition as given below. %do and if condition without % was causing that problem, either use the %if or if as per SAS syntax. after removing % form the do and end statement, fixed the macro and it worked just fine.*

```
 # incorrect Code I was using

    if condition then 
       statement 0
    else 
    %do;
        statement 1
        statement 2
    %end;

# Correct Code

    if condition then 
         statement 0
    else 
        do;
           statement 1
           statement 2
        end;
```